# Reclaim data(keyspaces) in persistentVolume kubernetes cassandra

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes

I have created Cassandra cluster using Kubernetes on AWS. I created volume as persistentVolume with reclaim policy as retain. But when I delete the pod(all instances) and recreate pod old data get lost.
Here is status of my setting.

---

```
$kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS    CLAIM                                   STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
pvc-1bc3f896-c0a5-11e8-84a8-02c7556b5a4a   320Gi      RWO            Retain           Bound     default/cassandra-storage-cassandra-1   gp2                      21d
pvc-f3ff4203-c0a4-11e8-84a8-02c7556b5a4a   320Gi      RWO            Retain           Bound     default/cassandra-storage-cassandra-0   gp2                      21d

$kubectl get pvc
NAME                            STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
cassandra-storage-cassandra-0   Bound     pvc-f3ff4203-c0a4-11e8-84a8-02c7556b5a4a   320Gi      RWO            gp2            21d
cassandra-storage-cassandra-1   Bound     pvc-1bc3f896-c0a5-11e8-84a8-02c7556b5a4a   320Gi      RWO            gp2            21d

$kubectl get pods 
NAME          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cassandra-0   1/1       Running   0          39s
cassandra-1   1/1       Running   0          27s

$kubectl get statefulsets                                                                                                                                                                           
NAME        DESIRED   CURRENT   AGE
cassandra   2         2         1m

----
```

Now if I add some data(keyspaces, tables) and then delete statefulsets and again recreate it, old data(keyspaces, tables) are missing. As my policy is reclaim, it should be there.

### Here is my statefulset creation yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: cassandra
  labels:
    app: cassandra
spec:
  serviceName: cassandra
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cassandra
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cassandra
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 180
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
            labelSelector:
              matchLabels:
                app: cassandra
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: MAX_HEAP_SIZE
              value: 1024M
            - name: HEAP_NEWSIZE
              value: 1024M
            - name: CASSANDRA_SEEDS
              value: "cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local"
            - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
              value: "CassandraCluster"
            - name: CASSANDRA_DC
              value: "DC1-Cassandra"
            - name: CASSANDRA_RACK
              value: "Rack1-Cassandra"
            - name: POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
          image: library/cassandra
          name: cassandra
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /cassandra-storage
              name: cassandra-storage
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: cassandra-storage
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 320Gi
```

---

Configuration of PV are as follows.

```
$kubectl describe pv                                                                                                                                                                                [10:33]
Name:            pvc-1bc3f896-c0a5-11e8-84a8-02c7556b5a4a
Labels:          failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=us-west-2
                 failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=us-west-2b
Annotations:     kubernetes.io/createdby=aws-ebs-dynamic-provisioner
                 pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller=yes
                 pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by=kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    gp2
Status:          Bound
Claim:           default/cassandra-storage-cassandra-1
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
Capacity:        320Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:         
Source:
    Type:       AWSElasticBlockStore (a Persistent Disk resource in AWS)
    VolumeID:   aws://us-west-2b/vol-0dceef39c7948c69e
    FSType:     ext4
    Partition:  0
    ReadOnly:   false
Events:         <none>


Name:            pvc-f3ff4203-c0a4-11e8-84a8-02c7556b5a4a
Labels:          failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=us-west-2
                 failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=us-west-2b
Annotations:     kubernetes.io/createdby=aws-ebs-dynamic-provisioner
                 pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller=yes
                 pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by=kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    gp2
Status:          Bound
Claim:           default/cassandra-storage-cassandra-0
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
Capacity:        320Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:         
Source:
    Type:       AWSElasticBlockStore (a Persistent Disk resource in AWS)
    VolumeID:   aws://us-west-2b/vol-07c16900909f80cd1
    FSType:     ext4
    Partition:  0
    ReadOnly:   false
Events:         <none>
```

---

am I missing some setting or reclaim is not possible when all statefulset get deleted, only individual pod deletion/restart can claim the volume data?

Comment: The Retain reclaim policy for a PV refers to the fact that the space used for that PV will not be return to the pool and reused for other PV's when the PVC bounded with the PV is deleted. If you want to reuse the data in a new Pod of your Statefulset, you should not delete the PVC.

Comment: Could you share configuration for your PV, cause it looks like you have 2 of them, and also, it requires to understand how PVCs bind to them.

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev Edited with PV configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your Cassandra's mountPath "/cassandra-storage" is not right, if you did not change your Cassandra data path, the default Cassandra data path is "/var/lib/cassandra/data", so you need to change the volume mountPath to "/var/lib/cassandra/data" in your Cassandra yaml file.